# NvCplGetThermalSettings call to nvcpl.dll returns false (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, gpu, temperature

I'm trying to retrieve GPU temperature information using the code below (not mine; slightly modified), but get a 'false' return when I attempt to call the .dll function, nvCplGetThermalSettings:

```
HINSTANCE lib = LoadLibraryA("nvcpl.dll");
if(lib)
{
    NvCplGetThermalSettings nvCplGetThermalSettings = reinterpret_cast<NvCplGetThermalSettings> (GetProcAddress(lib,"NvCplGetThermalSettings"));
    DWORD coreTemp,ambientTemp,upperLimit;
    int success = nvCplGetThermalSettings(0,&coreTemp,&ambientTemp,&upperLimit);
    if(!success) {
        printf("Call failed: %d\n", success);
    }
    else {
        char text[128];
        printf(
            "Core Temp:    %d°\n"
            "Ambient Temp:    %d°\n"
            "Upper Limit:    %d°",coreTemp,ambientTemp,upperLimit);
    }
    FreeLibrary(lib);
}
else {
     printf("Couldn't load library.\n");
}
```

The .dll is being loaded, is relatively up to date (2013), and applications such as GPU-Z are able to display this information, so I know it's not a hardware/driver issue. Any ideas appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else was interested in the solution, using nvapi64.dll did the trick, but required replicating a few structs using non-API-specific objects and some digging through headers. Functional code is as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#define NVAPI_MAX_THERMAL_SENSORS_PER_GPU 3
typedef enum 
{
    NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_NONE          = 0,
    NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_GPU           = 1,     //!< GPU core temperature requires NvPhysicalGpuHandle
    NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_MEMORY        = 2,     //!< GPU memory temperature requires NvPhysicalGpuHandle
    NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_POWER_SUPPLY  = 4,     //!< GPU power supply temperature requires NvPhysicalGpuHandle
    NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_BOARD         = 8,     //!< GPU board ambient temperature requires NvPhysicalGpuHandle
    NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_VCD_BOARD     = 9,     //!< Visual Computing Device Board temperature requires NvVisualComputingDeviceHandle
    NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_VCD_INLET     = 10,    //!< Visual Computing Device Inlet temperature requires NvVisualComputingDeviceHandle
    NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_VCD_OUTLET    = 11,    //!< Visual Computing Device Outlet temperature requires NvVisualComputingDeviceHandle

    NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_ALL           = 15,
    NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_UNKNOWN       = -1,
} NV_THERMAL_TARGET;

typedef struct
{
    int   version;                //!< structure version 
    int   count;                  //!< number of associated thermal sensors
    struct 
    {
        int       controller;        //!< internal, ADM1032, MAX6649...
        int                       defaultMinTemp;    //!< The min default temperature value of the thermal sensor in degree Celsius 
        int                       defaultMaxTemp;    //!< The max default temperature value of the thermal sensor in degree Celsius 
        int                       currentTemp;       //!< The current temperature value of the thermal sensor in degree Celsius 
        NV_THERMAL_TARGET           target;            //!< Thermal sensor targeted @ GPU, memory, chipset, powersupply, Visual Computing Device, etc.
    } sensor[NVAPI_MAX_THERMAL_SENSORS_PER_GPU];

} NV_GPU_THERMAL_SETTINGS;

// magic numbers, do not change them
#define NVAPI_MAX_PHYSICAL_GPUS   64
#define NVAPI_MAX_USAGES_PER_GPU  34

// function pointer types
typedef int *(*NvAPI_QueryInterface_t)(unsigned int offset);
typedef int (*NvAPI_Initialize_t)();
typedef int (*NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs_t)(int **handles, int *count);
typedef int (*NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages_t)(int *handle, unsigned int *usages);
typedef int (*NvAPI_GPU_GetThermalSettings_t)(int *handle, int sensorIndex, NV_GPU_THERMAL_SETTINGS *temp);

int main()
{   
    HMODULE hmod = LoadLibraryA("nvapi64.dll");
    if (hmod == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't find nvapi.dll" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // nvapi.dll internal function pointers
    NvAPI_QueryInterface_t      NvAPI_QueryInterface     = NULL;
    NvAPI_Initialize_t          NvAPI_Initialize         = NULL;
    NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs_t    NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs   = NULL;
    NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages_t       NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages      = NULL;
    NvAPI_GPU_GetThermalSettings_t  NvAPI_GPU_GetThermalSettings = NULL;

    // nvapi_QueryInterface is a function used to retrieve other internal functions in nvapi.dll
    NvAPI_QueryInterface = (NvAPI_QueryInterface_t) GetProcAddress(hmod, "nvapi_QueryInterface");

    // some useful internal functions that aren't exported by nvapi.dll
    NvAPI_Initialize = (NvAPI_Initialize_t) (*NvAPI_QueryInterface)(0x0150E828);
    NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs = (NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs_t) (*NvAPI_QueryInterface)(0xE5AC921F);
    NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages = (NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages_t) (*NvAPI_QueryInterface)(0x189A1FDF);
    NvAPI_GPU_GetThermalSettings = (NvAPI_GPU_GetThermalSettings_t) (*NvAPI_QueryInterface)(0xE3640A56);

    if (NvAPI_Initialize == NULL || NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs == NULL ||
        NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs == NULL || NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't get functions in nvapi.dll" << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    // initialize NvAPI library, call it once before calling any other NvAPI functions
    (*NvAPI_Initialize)();
    NV_GPU_THERMAL_SETTINGS          nvgts;
    int          gpuCount = 0;
    int          gpuTemp;
    int         *gpuHandles[NVAPI_MAX_PHYSICAL_GPUS] = { NULL };
    unsigned int gpuUsages[NVAPI_MAX_USAGES_PER_GPU] = { 0 };

    // gpuUsages[0] must be this value, otherwise NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages won't work
    gpuUsages[0] = (NVAPI_MAX_USAGES_PER_GPU * 4) | 0x10000;

    (*NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs)(gpuHandles, &gpuCount);
    nvgts.version = sizeof(NV_GPU_THERMAL_SETTINGS) | (1<<16);
    nvgts.count = 0;
    nvgts.sensor[0].controller = -1;
    nvgts.sensor[0].target = NVAPI_THERMAL_TARGET_GPU;

    // print GPU usage every second
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        (*NvAPI_GPU_GetThermalSettings)(gpuHandles[0], 0 ,&nvgts);
        printf("%d\n", nvgts.sensor[0].currentTemp);
        (*NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages)(gpuHandles[0], gpuUsages);
        int usage = gpuUsages[3];
        std::cout << "GPU Usage: " << usage << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```